# SIngle point of failure in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

while doing a tutorial on `Cassandra`, the instructor mentioned that `cassandra` has no `single point of failure`. That is, if a node is down in a cluster, it should not affect the way client access it.

SO I tried the following:
Turning down one of nodes in my 3 node cluster.

Then try to connect to that turned Down Node.

I was refused connection which is obvious because that node is down. But i was expecting cassandra to route the connection to next node in a round-robin fashion as the instructor mentioned. But it did not.
why is that?

```
ccm status
node1: UP
node3: UP
node2: UP
ccm node2 stop
ccm status
node1: UP
node3: UP
node2: DOWN
ccm node2 cqlsh
Connection error: Could not connect to 127.0.0.2:9160
```

**EDIT**:

One more thing I noticed is I was able to do a write operation. But the default operation failed. I did not tweak consistency levels. I am using the default. Here what I get:

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE example with replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
cqlsh> use example ;
cqlsh:example> CREATE TABLE users(id varchar PRIMARY KEY, email varchar, password varchar, name varchar);
cqlsh:example> INSERT INTO users (id, email, name, password) VALUES ('user1','user1@example.com','foo','foo_pwd');
cqlsh:example> SELECT * from users ;
Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the node is down and the driver you are using does not save state then it doesn't know what node to connect to. If you were using any of the newer generation of drivers you would see that you can continue to execute queries even if the node you initially connected to went down.

DataStax Python Driver Example:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
sessions = Cluster("127.0.0.1").connect()
session.execute("Select * from ks.tab")

#Turn off Cassandra 127.0.0.1

session.execute("select * from ks.tab") # Will be ok if replication on ks is more than 1 and CL is one
```

Edit:

Replication level and Consistency Level
Both of these are described in detail [in this blog post](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/post/consistency-cassandra/)

What you are observing is this:

An insert will succeed at the default consistency (one) as long as the node which is responsible for it's hashed key is up. So even with an RF of 1, A downed node will still allow many writes (and reads) to still succeed. If you keep trying other values you'll see roughly 1/3 of your input choices hash to the broken node and you get an unavailable exception.

Select * though requires checking data on EVERY node which means if any of the nodes are down, this command will fail (unless RF>1)

Comment: I am using cassandra cluster manager. I don't know if it supports saving state. In the example you provided, what is the next node that gets connected? FOr example, Node 1 knows its neighbours nodes. I connect to Node 1. but if Node 1 is known, how is the neighbour node information is retrived, so that client can forward its request to other nodes?

Comment: THanks for the updated answer. This explains very clearly. Can you please see my comment above and give your opinion.

Comment: CCM is not the client/driver. It's simply a tool that starts up Cassandra Clusters.  CQLSH uses the python driver so it knows the state of the cluster but only after initially communicating with one node. When it connects to that first note, the driver learns all the topology of the cluster and establishes connections with the other nodes. The order in which queries are executed is based on another different strategy chosen in the driver. The default is Local Round Robin, which hits a node responsible for the partition first and then alternates between the rest of the nodes.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation. you mention "CQLSH uses the python driver so it knows the state of the cluster but only after initially communicating with one node.". If the node to which the driver connects first is down, what happens then?

Comment: Then it doesn't connect. You can add in several connect points if thats an issue. I'm not sure if cqlsh allows that but the api for the python driver does.

Comment: Thanks! I am planning to use python driver. But have you used cqlengine which is python API for CQL3 object mapper

Comment: I have not yet, but I have a lot of respect for their dev team.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Setting the 'replication_factor' to 2 instead of 1 fixed it for me.  Many examples seem to show replication_factor of 1 for single node setups.

The first step should have been:

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE example with replication = 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 2};
```

Alternatively, I used the following steps to [modify the existing keyspace configuration](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/create_keyspace_c.html):

```
cqlsh> ALTER KEYSPACE example WITH REPLICATION = {'replication_factor' : 2 };
```

or

```
#using the deprecated Cassandra-cli (this is what I initially found as a solution)
UPDATE KEYSPACE example WITH strategy_options = {replication_factor:2};
```

followed by running the following:

```
nodetool repair
```

Wait for the repair process to complete, then confirm with:

```
nodetool status
#should show 'own %' as ~67% for a 3 node setup.
```